# Jetty sealed javax.naming

Tags: java, maven, jetty, jndi, torque

I have a legacy application using struts 1 and torque. I have made an effort last week to refactor it a bit and tried to decouple some groups of classes and introduced unit tests. As I can not test all areas of the application through unit tests, I wanted to add HtmlUnit tests.

To to this, I added the maven-failsafe-plugin and jetty to my project, like so:

```
<build>
...
  <plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>integration-test</goal>
                   <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.16</version>
      <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
          <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>start-jetty</id>
              <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                  <daemon>true</daemon>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
              <id>stop-jetty</id>
              <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>stop</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem is, that when I run mvn verify, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package javax.naming: already loaded
```

I am using javax.naming in some classes, but can't find any dependency that overrides javax.naming!

Does anybody have a clue about how to figure this problem out?